# Proof by induction for an inequality relationship

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, induction

[image: Question]
The question asks to prove the relationship stated below via proof by induction. The general approach is to start with an n value of 1; validate whether the left-handed side and the right-handed side are equivalent. Then, entering induction: first an assumption is made for the value n=a. For n=a, the statement is assumed to be true; and when the statement is true for n=a, it must be true for n=a+1 also.

Here's the overall approach I made so far:

[image: Approach]

Yet, in the induction part for n=a+1, it seems that the desired result equivalent to the right-handed side does not get derived.

I want to ask whether an appropriate approach is made for this proof; how to organize the expression below in order to show the statement is valid.

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your induction hypothesis involves an  an inequality and not an equation. You have to fix that.

To conclude, you can use the following:

\begin{align}
\frac{a^k(a+1)+2(a+1)^k}{2} &= \frac{a(a)^{k-1}(a+1) + 2(a+1)^k}{2} \\&\le \frac{a(a+1)^{k-1}(a+1) + 2(a+1)^k}{2}  \\&= \frac{(a+1)^k (a)+2(a+1)^k}{2} \\&= \frac{(a+1)^k(a+2)}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: Regarding the very last fraction, wouldn't it be (a+1)^k * (a+3) / 2, instead of a+2?

Comment: thanks. i have edited my answer. btw, please try to iedit your post to use mathjax, for a start, surround mathematical object with the dollar signs.